# Java Botframework for MS Teams - How to send a proactive message for a specific conversation

Tags: java, spring-boot, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

Would anyone know hot to send a proactive message for a specific conversation? I'm using Java in botframework for teams, and I was reading the documentation, it seems that you can only send to a specific receiver with the sample of creating a new thred in a teams channel. If I want to send a person or multiple persons with conversationId for example it's not possible. This is the code from the sample of proactive messages that I'm using for reference

```
@RestController
public class NotifyController {
    /**
     * The BotFrameworkHttpAdapter to use. Note is is provided by dependency
     * injection via the constructor.
     *
     * @see com.microsoft.bot.integration.spring.BotDependencyConfiguration
     */
    private final BotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter;

    private ConversationReferences conversationReferences;
    private String appId;

    @Autowired
    public NotifyController(
        BotFrameworkHttpAdapter withAdapter,
        Configuration withConfiguration,
        ConversationReferences withReferences
    ) {
        adapter = withAdapter;
        conversationReferences = withReferences;
        appId = withConfiguration.getProperty("MicrosoftAppId");
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/notify")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> proactiveMessage() {
        for (ConversationReference reference : conversationReferences.values()) {
            adapter.continueConversation(
                appId, reference, turnContext -> turnContext.sendActivity("proactive hello").thenApply(resourceResponse -> null)
            );
        }

        // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
            "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
            HttpStatus.ACCEPTED
        );
    }
}
```

Someone know how to do this?

Comment: Please refer to below docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp  Also refer this: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-newemployeeonboarding/blob/main/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.NewHireOnboarding/Helpers/NotificationHelper.cs#L101

Comment: Is your issue resolved or are you still looking for any help?

Comment: I'm still looking for help

Comment: To send proactive messages, acquire a conversation reference from an incoming message using TurnContext.getConversationReference(), then use adapter.continueConversation() to create a TurnContext object that will allow the bot to deliver the new outgoing message. https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/16.proactive-messages#readme